# iPad retina landing page size - 2MB

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

The landing page for an ipad retina (i.e 1536 x 2048) is about 2MB. Apple seems to mandate using a PNG for landing pages. Is it possible to reduce this file size? (my landing page is really simple already)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually the byte size of image not only depends upon the resolution but also on bit depth.
e.g. 100x100 PNG 16bit/24bit

you can reduce the bit depth of the png if you feel like it is not affecting the image quality and if you do find the image quality becomes unacceptable on reducing bit depth then your image is not that simple.

you can also use colors/gradient instead of an image so that you can completely remove the image

you can also use the tiled image (if it suits you) and can keep a small image in the resources.

see... you have lots of choices my friend..!!

Answer (score 3):

I am using ImageOptim to reduce all my images. Works great and fast. Just download, open and drag and drop a folder or all your images onto the interface.

http://imageoptim.com/

There is even a case study on how well this tool can be used to shrink your iOS-Apps:

http://imageoptim.com/tweetbot.html

Answer (score 2):

Use [Image Optimiser](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/imageoptimizer/). You can optimise image online.

Comment: If this doesn't work google for image optimiser, you will find many softwares.